# Accidentally formatted partition, want to recover files

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I had elementary OS luna installed in my hdd, a few days before, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 in another partition (ext4) .  I accidentally formatted the partition containing ubuntu (to ext4) , I realised it instantly and unmounted the formatted drive and haven't written anything to it until now. How to get the partition back ?

Will my grub bootloader work ? I have ubuntu installed last , if it fails what should i do ?

```
    fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000361e8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1       921059328   976773119    27856896   83  Linux
/dev/sda3   *        2046   419635199   209816577    5  Extended
/dev/sda4       419635200   921059327   250712064    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       251867136   252893183      513024   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       252895232   419635199    83369984   83  Linux
/dev/sda7            2048   125042963    62520458   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       125044736   251867135    63411200   83  Linux
```

sda8 is the accidentally formatted drive.

Answer (score -1):

you can set up your grub boot loader to start with defined OS.if you cannot do it,start computer with live CD and find grub boot loader file.edit that.it is impossible to recover back datas in formatted part.I suggest Remastersys to backup your OS clone as iso file perodicly.Anyway God help you man! I wish you did not have important files in that formatted part :)

Comment: yeah, I had important project files, but anyway thanks for mentioning a way to prevent this.